# Auto Create statistics in Azure SQL DW

Tags: azure-synapse

In Azure SQL Datawarehouse i just used the below tsql code to enable auto statistics creation.The command ran successfully , but when i checked in database properties under option tab Auto Create Statistics is till set to False.

```
ALTER DATABASE MyDB SET AUTO_CREATE_STATISTICS ON;
```

Please let  me know if i'm missing here something. I have the db_owner access for the database also.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you are using SQL Server Management Studio.

I was able to reproduce the symptom by turning off and on auto_create_statistics.

The issue appears to be that the database metadata is cached in SSMS. Right-click the database name and select "Refresh" before selecting "Properties". Using this method I got the correct setting for auto_create_statistics showing up each time.

My tests were done using SSMS 17.7

(The need to refresh the database metadata can also occur when adding or removing tables, columns, etc)

Comment: The issue is still there, im using SSMS 17.9 even after executing the Alter database statement and refreshing the database the Auto Create Statistics is still showing False. Please let me know what might be the issue

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't replicate your problem. Please check the results of the query suggested by Ron Ortloff to ensure that the correct setting has been made in DW: "select name,is_auto_create_stats_on from sys.databases;". Does it show the correct value of 1/0? Sorry for asking basic questions, but are you sure you are setting the right database name in the ALTER TABLE statement? Are you running REFRESH on the same database name? If all of these are correct, you may need to raise a support call.

Answer (score 0):

You can also query sys.databases, the is_auto_create_stats_on column.

Comment: Same result alter database statement running successfully but while querying sys.databases the result for column 'is_auto_create_stats_on' is set to 0. Please help